# Why clojure starts with 'M-x slime' for my Aquamacs without any setup?

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, aquamacs, elpa

I have Aquamacs running on my Mac.

I installed the [ESK for Aquamacs](http://github.com/walter/aquamacs-emacs-starter-kit) and it installs ELPA at ~/.emacs.d/elpa. With ELPA, I installed clojure-mode/clojure-est-mode/slime/slime-repl/swank-clojure.

The thing is that when I run 'M-x slime', clojure is run. Why is this? I'm curious as I don't have any setup for slime in my .emacs and even in /Users/smcho/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/{Preferences.el, customizations.el}. I mean, I don't have (setq inferior-lisp-program "clojure") or something.

Or, does it have to do with my 'swank-clojure' installation? I see something like this at the *inferior-lisp* buffer.

```
(require 'swank.swank)
(swank.swank/ignore-protocol-version nil)
...
#ServerSocket ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=51847]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of `swank-clojure.el`, a deprecated elisp program. Don't use it, as per my [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550971/what-does-the-swank-clojure-do-exactly-and-do-we-have-swank-something-else), on your next question. It may have bugs and thus isn't suitable to use. Use `M-x slime-connect` instead, after starting swank up with `lein swank`.

Comment: I believe you mean deprecated, unless `swank-clojure.el` has declined in value recently...

Answer (score 1):

As Isaac said, swank-clojure.el sets 'slime-lisp-implementations' for clojure (in short, a way to start java with swank-clojure in classpath so that swank can be started). Then slime connects to this port and you get the repl.

The problem with this approach is that, you will need to setup classpath upfront. This gets tedious for each and every project you want to work on. So, best way is to use M-x swank-clojure-project or lein swank and then M-x slime-connect. I prefer swank-clojure-project.